# WPF DataGridRow - Considering multiple conditions in Triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

Working with a WPF datagrid, I need to comply with these requeriments:

- Change row background when IsMouseOver.
- Change row background to red when a critical property is met.
- Change row background to violet when a row is selected, but not critical.
- Change row background to dark red when a row is selected and critical.

I cannot met the last condition so far. My code right now is:

```
<Style x:Key="GridRow" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E5E5E5" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5F5F5" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStatusCritical}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#660066" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using [MultiDataTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx). Just make sure that you place them in the correct order, as I recall, the last trigger that meets all criteria takes precedence.